# Warning library WMP in C#

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a warning. I want to fix it, but I do not know, please help me!

> Warning: Type library importer encountered a property getter 'sessionPlaylistCount' on type 'WMPLib.IWMPNowPlayingHelperDispatch' without a valid return type.  The importer will attempt to import this property as a method instead.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi and welcome on stackoverflow. Please be more specific: What are you trying to do? What kind of warning is this, by the compiler? Are you using Visual Studio? Please show some of your code, too.

Comment: Please show the return type of `'sessionPlaylistCount`.

Comment: I want to remove the warning. I add axWindowsMediaPlayer project, VS 2008 Pro, Win7 64bit. (Sorry, I'm not fluent in English)

Comment: I don't use "sessionPlaylistCount" in my project. I tried them all but I don't see

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mKn43.png

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question for where the warning comes from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796731/build-warnings-related-to-com-reference-version-1-0-type-library-and-vs-2010. It is safe to ignore. I am not sure whether or not you can disable the warning.