# VB 2010 Error after Win10 upgrade

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the following error on my project since I have upgraded my PC to Windows 10.

> Warning   2 Processing COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
>   from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\MSWORD.OLB". Type library importer encountered a
>   property getter 'Dummy1' on type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document' without a valid return type.
>   The importer will attempt to import this property as a method
>   instead.  License Form All APPs

Can anyone help?

Comment: any help, project had no errors before windows 10 upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Warnings Related to COM Reference (Version 1.0 Type Library) and VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796731/build-warnings-related-to-com-reference-version-1-0-type-library-and-vs-2010)